# Get a row by particular category SQLite android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I've a table "itemsDataTable" and one of the columns is 'Category'.
I looked & searched but didn't got my answer.
I want to get all the rows in the table with a specific category (like 'Electronic') and store it.

Comment: Do you know anything about SQL?  This is a very basic `where` clause.

Comment: actually no because i used to get all the data from the database, store it to HashMap and do whatever i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need learn SQL first:
[Google it!](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en-US&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=hp&tok=GjohJL9BM4wTi1ghykpSmg&cp=9&gs_id=8&xhr=t&q=sql%20basics&pf=p&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=sql%20basis&gs_l=&pbx=1&qscrl=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&fp=f324b4352f85d59f&bpcl=40096503&biw=1366&bih=682&ion=1)

To answer your question:

```
SELECT * FROM itemsDataTable WHERE category LIKE 'ELETRONIC'
```

Also, search for Object-relational Mapping in Google!

Comment: thanks!
i know how to store it (will do in HashMap), but i'll definitely need to learn SQL more.